# A start job is running for dev-md2.device

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, filesystems, centos7

I was following steps to setup a machine for virtualization and then ran into the following problem.

When rebooting after the installing it wants to boot into the 3.x kernel which I guess is needed for QEMU since that was the kernel the RPM installed.

What I get on bootup:[image]

```
 blkid
/dev/nvme1n1: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: LABEL="EFI_SYSPART" UUID="3362-BDF8" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ff3fe520-fa6d-4958-8a79-76317a9370c0"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="f8fc353e-e8d6-5290-a4d2-adc226fd5302" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="c802a898-abdc-4530-b1e3-c809e1f8e482"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="986f7ff9-d263-f2f7-a4d2-adc226fd5302" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="974d4361-10f3-4d91-8980-ceab78efb29a"
/dev/nvme1n1p4: LABEL="swap-nvme1n1p4" UUID="a536ddcf-1637-4140-9c90-2cffc8fced00" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ddefa7c0-91c8-432c-a5be-ad3e11535162"
/dev/md3: LABEL="/home" UUID="d6375286-a869-41fb-b667-4937e2ba74fc" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md2: LABEL="/" UUID="15819e95-ab11-4463-9e6f-8b408b460700" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="EFI_SYSPART" UUID="32C3-5E9E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="5d8775f4-ba9f-4372-9520-ec1dc18a2036"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="f8fc353e-e8d6-5290-a4d2-adc226fd5302" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ae5e1127-cf8d-4d6b-94f6-2500d929d520"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="986f7ff9-d263-f2f7-a4d2-adc226fd5302" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a785ccf1-ce77-4361-ad0a-769ef6be4c65"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="swap-nvme0n1p4" UUID="b091c71e-ea3f-4a64-b13c-d934344a23fa" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="1b8704a2-7339-41fa-a6ac-67da0cd8c496"
```

and

```
cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md3        /home   ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/nvme0n1p4  swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
/dev/nvme0n1p1  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
```

Will boot find on this kernel:

```
4.4.30-mod-std-ipv6-64 #9 SMP Tue Nov 1 17:58:26 CET 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But when I try to boot to this kernel I keep getting the error and shown above.

```
CentOS Linux (3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you `mdadm` configuration is incorrect. Run:

```
mdadm -D --scan
```

to see available RAID arrays and update your `mdadm.conf` accordingly (probably located in `/etc/mdadm/mdam.conf`).

Finally you need to update `initramfs`:

```
update-initramfs -u
```